# Dynamic Dropdowns with AJAX, Jquery, and Codeigniter Help: Firebug not showing errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am having trouble getting ajax to work with my "dynamic combo box."  First here is the code:
The View:

```
<?php echo form_open('control_form/add_all'); ?>
    <label for="make">State<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <select id="make" name="make" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        foreach($makeOptions->result() as $make){
            echo '<option value="' . $make->make_id . '">' . $make->make . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label for="model">City<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <!--this will be filled based on the tree selection above-->
    <select id="model" name="model"> 
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <label for="f_membername">Member Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="f_membername"/>-->
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The View Controller:

```
    function dropDown(){
         if ($this->ion_auth->requireAdmin())         
        $data = array('title' => 'DropDown', 'main_content' =>     'admin/dropDown');        
        $data['makeOptions'] = $this->vehicle_model->getMake(Null, Null);
        $data['modelOptions'] = $this->vehicle_model->getModel(Null, Null, NULL, Null);            
        $this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);          
}
```

The Ajax controller:

```
   function get_model($make){    
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode($this->vehicle_model->getModelByMake ($make)));
}
```

The Jquery:

```
$('#model').hide();
 $('#make').change(function(){
var make_id = $('#make').val();
if (make_id != ""){
    var post_url = "http://pulsedrivers.com/admin/get_model/" + make_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: post_url,
         success: function(models) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
          {
            $('#model').empty();
            $('#model').show();
               $.each(models,function(model_id,model) 
               {
                var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option for each group
                  opt.val(model_id);
                  opt.text(model);
                  $('#model').append(opt); 
            });
           } //end success
     }); //end AJAX
} else {
    $('#model').empty();
    $('#model').hide();
}//end if
}); //end change
```

The Model (used by get_model controller):

```
function getModelByMake ($make, $tree = null){
    $this->db->select('model_id, model, make_id');

    if($tree != NULL){
        $this->db->where('make_id', $make);
    }
        $this->db->where('make_id', $make);
    $query = $this->db->get('model');
    $models = array();

    if($query->result()){
        foreach ($query->result() as $model) {
            $models[$model->model_id] = $model->model;
        }
        return $models;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The view contains two dropdowns, one displays makes, the other the corresponding models.  The models are not showing up after a make is selected.  Firebug does not show any errors during the process.

Things already checked: jquery works, the script loads.

The controller get_models returns an array like this 1:Corvette, 2:Camaro so that seems its works correctly as well.

Any help is gratefully appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my script was incorrect.  For future reference to fellow noobies like myseleft to jquery and ajax.  If you want your script to start on page open, wrap your code with this function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 });
```

Also, Codeigniter related, turn CSFR Token to false. (development purposes only, once you go live you will need to set it to true for security reasons).  I will now need to look up how to use my script with CSFR token set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for your problem is either you are duplicating a method in the model means you are defining a method in the model twice or there is a syntex error in your model code. Try calling the model method without ajax just for testing and you wioll see the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, the get_model function which calls onto the model returns a json array of the query.  I model did have a duplicate but after i fixed it and tried again, it still doesnt work.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: instead of returning json array from model pass it to controller and there use this echo json_encode($result). Dont forget to echo because just passing is not enough ajax get only that data which is echoed also if its not working check for syntex errors

Comment: I dont know if I understand right, as you probaly know, I am new to this.  I did however run the controller that calls out the json array with a id number (so the model can query the result based in it).  I get a pop up asking me to download a file, I open it up with a text editor and get this inside it:  {"60":"FX","6":"G"} The first variable is the id number and the second is the model.  Does this mean my model and controller is working fine?

Comment: yes you should also add dataType : 'json' in your ajax request and try to find out why it is saying to download instead of just echoing to ajax request